# Align Alignment.bottomCenter not help in Row

Tags: android, flutter

Android Studio 2.6
Flutter plugin.

I need 4 dots to put bottom and center over image.

I try to use Align widget like this:

```
Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
```

but it not help. The dots shop on the top.

Here code:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import '../constants.dart' as Constants;

  Widget _createCarouselContainer() {
    final List<String> imagesFullPathList = [
      'assets/images/campaign1.png'
    ];
    int _current = 0;
    return Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [_createBoxShadow()]),
        child: new ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(Constants.ROUNDED_CORNER_RADIUS)),
            child: new Stack(children: [
              CarouselSlider(
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                      onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                        _current = index;
                        _logger.d(
                            "_createCarouselContainer: _current = $_current");
                      },
                      autoPlay: true,
                      viewportFraction: 1.0, // page fills 100% of the carousel
                      height: Constants.CARD_VIEW_HEIGHT),
                  items: imagesFullPathList
                      .map((imageName) => Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: AssetImage(imageName),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList()),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Row(
                    children: imagesFullPathList.map((url) {
                      int index = imagesFullPathList.indexOf(url);
                      _logger.d("_createCarouselContainer: index =  $index");
                      return Container(
                        width: 10.0,
                        height: 10.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: _current == index
                              ? Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                              : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ))
            ])));
  }
```

and here result:

[image]

Why `Align` not help?

Comment: have you used Flutter inspector to check if your row is actually occupying the entire space?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`Positioned Widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) inside `Stack Widget` instead of `Align`

to align `Widget` at the bottom center using `Positioned` use

```
bottom: 0,
left: 0,
right: 0,
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
Widget _createCarouselContainer() {
    final List<String> imagesFullPathList = [
      'assets/images/campaign1.png'
    ];
    int _current = 0;
    return Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [_createBoxShadow()]),
        child: new ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(Constants.ROUNDED_CORNER_RADIUS)),
            child: new Stack(children: [
              CarouselSlider(
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                      onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                        _current = index;
                        _logger.d(
                            "_createCarouselContainer: _current = $_current");
                      },
                      autoPlay: true,
                      viewportFraction: 1.0, // page fills 100% of the carousel
                      height: Constants.CARD_VIEW_HEIGHT),
                  items: imagesFullPathList
                      .map((imageName) => Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: AssetImage(imageName),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList()),
              Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Row(
                    children: imagesFullPathList.map((url) {
                      int index = imagesFullPathList.indexOf(url);
                      _logger.d("_createCarouselContainer: index =  $index");
                      return Container(
                        width: 10.0,
                        height: 10.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: _current == index
                              ? Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                              : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ))
            ])));
  }
```

Comment: OK, now it's in the bottom. But I need bottom and center. How I can do this?

Comment: You can use left property of positioned widget and find size of screen using media query and divide it by 2.

Comment: @NileshRathod Not. Help. Dots in the bottom and LEFT. But  I need bottom and center

Comment: @a_subscriber have you tried both propety `left: 0,
right: 0,` to make it in center?

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes, but it not help

Comment: @a_subscriber try to add `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,` in your `Stack` widget

Comment: @a_subscriber strange for me `left: 0, right: 0,` working fine

Comment: @NileshRathod new Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children ... not help. Is in the bottom and LEFT

Comment: @a_subscriber may be an issue with your `Row` widget another way tri to add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` in row widget

Comment: @NileshRathod I copy and paste your code but it not help

Comment: @NileshRathod I find solution. I added my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution (by `MediaQuery` and `Positioned`).

```
Widget _createCarouselContainer(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> imagesFullPathList = [
      'assets/images/campaign1.png',
    ];
    double dotContainerWidth = 12.0;
    double dotContainerHeight = 12.0;
    double dotHorizontalInsets = 2.0;
    int _current = 0;
    double allDotsContainerWidth =
        dotContainerWidth * imagesFullPathList.length +
            ((imagesFullPathList.length - 1) * dotHorizontalInsets);
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [_createBoxShadow()]),
        child: new ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(Constants.ROUNDED_CORNER_RADIUS)),
            child: new Stack(children: [
              CarouselSlider(
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                      onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                        _current = index;
                        _logger.d(
                            "_createCarouselContainer: _current = $_current");
                      },
                      autoPlay: true,
                      viewportFraction: 1.0, // page fills 100% of the carousel
                      height: Constants.CARD_VIEW_HEIGHT),
                  items: imagesFullPathList
                      .map((imageName) => Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: AssetImage(imageName),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList()),
              Positioned(
                  // in Stack to align widget must use "Positioned"
                  bottom: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                  left: screenWidth / 2 - allDotsContainerWidth / 2,
                  child: Row(
                    children: imagesFullPathList.map((url) {
                      int index = imagesFullPathList.indexOf(url);
                      return Container(
                        width: dotContainerWidth,
                        height: dotContainerHeight,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: dotHorizontalInsets),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: _current == index
                              ? Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                              : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ))
            ])));
  }
```

and now dots are in the BOTTOM AND CENTER.
Here result:
[image]